# Converting multiple paths into one big 'connected' path in Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I drew a shape with lots of 'lines' in Expression blend.  In the XAML this gave me lots of small Paths.

I then used Object->Path->Make Compound Path

This brought them all into one path, but the lines are not 'connected' as I'd hoped.  It's still just lots of separate bits.

Is there any way to bring them together so that if I move one point, both connected lines move?  (As if I'd drawn the shape with the Pencil tool.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect the separate Paths rather than combine them.  Right-click the compound path and select "Path > Release Compound Path".  This should revert all the lines to separate Paths again.  Once that is done, follow these steps:

1. Select two of the Paths to connect (using Ctrl-click).
2. Activate the Pen tool.
3. Click the end point of one Path (it should turn blue)
4. Click the end point of the second Path.

This will connect the two Paths and turn them into one Path.  Repeat this process for each Line you drew originally.  You will most likely need to edit your final Path to clean it up some.

This can be a little touchy, but stick with it and you'll get the hang of it pretty quickly.  For more help, look up "paths, connecting" in the User Guide (F1).