# Combining canvas with multiple paths to one path

Tags: xaml, expression-blend, vector-graphics

I have a collection of paths in canvas and I need to convert them into one Path.

I'm trying to do that by Object->Combine->Unite but this option is not enabled.

I would be gratefull for any help.

This is my XAML:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Canvas x:Name="field" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500">
            <Canvas x:Name="Layer_2" Height="509.154" Canvas.Left="92.5" Canvas.Top="11.346" Width="350">

                <Path Data="F1M391.8379,54.6753C391.0249,44.3673,381.7899,40.5433,377.0209,39.9613C368.0439,38.8093,156.5579,11.6653,153.6879,11.4043C153.2659,11.3663,152.8279,11.3463,152.3859,11.3463C149.2859,11.3463,146.5969,12.2933,146.3009,12.4013L146.1119,12.4693L145.9329,12.5553L132.0459,19.2413L129.1479,21.5923C126.1149,25.5313,126.3449,30.2683,126.5119,34.4753C126.4769,53.7523,125.8859,380.4613,126.5149,399.9613C127.1799,420.5743,136.1569,422.8063,138.9229,423.0023C151.9159,426.1893,344.9659,473.5313,363.7739,477.2933C366.5159,477.8423,369.0429,478.1193,371.2839,478.1193C376.0709,478.1193,379.7899,476.8793,382.3579,474.4293C390.4349,470.3023,392.4539,463.7933,392.3649,460.4653C392.3759,443.3883,392.6119,64.4803,391.8379,54.6753" Stroke="Black" Height="466.773" Canvas.Left="33.727" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0" Width="266.181"/>
                <Path Data="F1M147.165,16.193L133.278,22.879C133.278,22.879,371.147,475.214,379.633,471.099L379.633,471.099C388.12,466.985,387.862,460.557,387.862,460.557L387.862,460.557C387.862,460.557,388.119,64.795,387.347,55.024L387.347,55.024C386.576,45.252,376.034,43.966,376.034,43.966L376.034,43.966C376.034,43.966,155.65,15.678,152.823,15.421L152.823,15.421C152.508,15.392,152.194,15.38,151.884,15.38L151.884,15.38C149.4,15.38,147.165,16.193,147.165,16.193" Height="455.747" Canvas.Left="40.778" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="4.034" Width="254.625">

                </Path>
                <Path Data="F1M130.009,34.09C130.009,34.09,129.37,380.042,130.009,399.865L130.009,399.865C130.648,419.688,138.963,419.049,138.963,419.049L138.963,419.049C138.963,419.049,344.871,469.567,364.055,473.404L364.055,473.404C383.238,477.241,381.32,465.092,381.32,465.092L381.32,465.092L381.32,65.424C380.681,48.798,365.334,47.519,365.334,47.519L365.334,47.519C365.334,47.519,156.228,21.94,141.52,21.301L141.52,21.301C141.178,21.286,140.847,21.279,140.524,21.279L140.524,21.279C126.96,21.279,130.009,34.09,130.009,34.09" Height="452.874" Canvas.Left="37.216" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="9.933" Width="251.658">

                </Path>
                <Path Data="F1M130.009,34.09C130.009,34.09,129.775,160.894,129.732,265.362L129.732,265.362C219.448,338.824,357.291,327.6,381.32,324.991L381.32,324.991L381.32,65.424C380.681,48.798,365.334,47.519,365.334,47.519L365.334,47.519C365.334,47.519,156.228,21.94,141.52,21.301L141.52,21.301C141.179,21.286,140.846,21.279,140.524,21.279L140.524,21.279C126.957,21.277,130.009,34.09,130.009,34.09" Height="305.882" Canvas.Left="37.215" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="9.933" Width="251.605">

                </Path>
                <Path Data="F1M381.3203,465.0918L381.3203,65.4238C380.6803,48.7978,365.3343,47.5188,365.3343,47.5188C365.3343,47.5188,156.2283,21.9398,141.5203,21.3008C136.9533,21.1028,134.1153,22.2608,132.3693,23.9518C133.9243,23.4038,135.8693,23.1128,138.3233,23.2188C153.0303,23.8588,362.1363,49.4378,362.1363,49.4378C362.1363,49.4378,377.4833,50.7158,378.1233,67.3418L378.1233,467.0098C378.1233,467.0098,378.7003,470.7098,375.9973,473.3818C382.2753,471.1958,381.3203,465.0918,381.3203,465.0918" Stroke="Black" Height="452.103" Canvas.Left="39.869" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="9.932" Width="249.003"/>
                <Path Data="F1M141.691,395.498C141.691,405.922,149.756,407.904,149.756,407.904L149.756,407.904C149.756,407.904,328.467,450.977,344.525,454.425L344.525,454.425C357.506,457.213,359.753,452.715,360.031,450.083L360.031,450.083C360.31,447.449,360.031,128.777,360.031,128.777L360.031,128.777L141.072,94.663C141.072,94.663,141.691,382.473,141.691,395.498" Height="360.642" Canvas.Left="48.572" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="83.317" Width="219.083">

                </Path>
                <Path Data="F1M360.1494,326.6006C360.1254,236.0256,360.0314,128.7776,360.0314,128.7776L141.0724,94.6626C141.0724,94.6626,141.2784,190.6626,141.4534,274.2856C215.1814,326.6436,314.5184,328.8516,360.1494,326.6006" Fill="White" Height="232.497" Canvas.Left="48.572" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="83.316" Width="219.077"/>
                <Path Data="F1M248.96,226.704L297.708,235.978L298.237,214.253L249.489,206.305z" Height="29.673" Canvas.Left="156.46" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="194.959" Width="49.277" Fill="Black">

                </Path>
                <Path Data="F1M137.934,45.137C137.156,54.738,138.193,85.353,138.193,85.353L138.193,85.353L363.661,119.083L362.883,73.937C362.883,73.937,362.623,66.153,352.245,65.116L352.245,65.116C341.867,64.078,149.869,37.612,149.869,37.612L149.869,37.612C149.869,37.612,148.852,37.423,147.411,37.423L147.411,37.423C144.079,37.423,138.477,38.435,137.934,45.137" Height="81.66" Canvas.Left="45.145" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="26.077" Width="226.016">

                </Path>

                <Path Data="F1M149.08,398.571L348.092,446.953L348.092,130.23L149.08,98.307z M154.067,394.082L154.067,103.794L198.458,110.821L198.458,404.857z M203.446,153.085L203.446,111.61L343.104,133.72L343.104,176.122z M203.446,175.032L203.446,157.075L245.843,164.069L245.843,182.026z M250.83,182.848L250.83,164.891L295.222,172.214L295.222,190.17z M300.209,190.992L300.209,173.036L343.104,180.111L343.104,198.068z M203.446,196.977L203.446,179.021L245.843,186.015L245.843,203.971z M250.83,204.794L250.83,186.838L295.222,194.16L295.222,212.116z M300.209,212.939L300.209,194.983L343.104,202.059L343.104,220.014z M203.446,217.453L203.446,200.968L245.843,207.961L245.843,224.884z M250.83,225.757L250.83,208.784L295.222,216.107L295.222,233.537z M300.209,234.412L300.209,216.928L343.104,224.004L343.104,241.93z M203.446,238.402L203.446,221.444L245.843,228.874L245.843,245.832z M250.83,246.706L250.83,229.748L295.222,237.528L295.222,254.486z M300.209,255.36L300.209,238.402L343.104,245.92L343.104,262.878z M203.446,261.346L203.446,242.393L245.843,249.822L245.843,268.776z M250.83,269.65L250.83,250.696L295.222,258.477L295.222,277.43z M300.209,278.304L300.209,259.351L343.104,266.868L343.104,285.822z M203.446,282.793L203.446,265.336L245.843,272.765L245.843,290.223z M250.83,291.096L250.83,273.64L295.222,281.42L295.222,298.877z M300.209,299.751L300.209,282.294L343.104,289.811L343.104,307.269z M203.446,302.289L203.446,286.783L245.843,294.213L245.843,310.447z M250.83,311.407L250.83,295.087L295.222,302.868L295.222,319.95z M300.209,320.909L300.209,303.742L343.104,311.259L343.104,329.163z M203.446,323.258L203.446,306.28L245.843,314.437L245.843,331.766z M250.83,332.767L250.83,315.397L295.222,323.939L295.222,341.675z M300.209,342.676L300.209,324.9L343.104,333.154L343.104,351.283z M203.446,343.741L203.446,327.248L245.843,335.756L245.843,352.827z M250.83,353.895L250.83,336.757L295.222,345.665L295.222,363.407z M300.209,364.476L300.209,346.666L343.104,355.274L343.104,373.668z M203.446,364.242L203.446,347.732L245.843,356.816L245.843,374.193z M250.83,375.363L250.83,357.885L295.222,367.398L295.222,385.781z M203.446,386.189L203.446,368.233L245.843,378.182L245.843,396.139z M300.209,386.951L300.209,368.467L343.104,377.658L343.104,397.018z M250.83,397.31L250.83,379.353L295.222,389.772L295.222,407.727z M203.446,406.069L203.446,390.178L245.843,400.129L245.843,416.36z M300.209,408.897L300.209,390.942L343.104,401.009L343.104,418.965z M250.83,417.57L250.83,401.3L295.222,411.718L295.222,428.346z M300.209,429.557L300.209,412.888L343.104,422.956L343.104,439.97z" Height="348.646" Canvas.Left="56.58" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="86.961" Width="199.012">
                    <Path.Stroke>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                    </Path.Stroke>
                </Path>
                <Path Data="F1M362.8828,73.937C362.8828,73.937,362.7278,69.445,358.1038,66.832C359.6468,69.006,359.7208,71.126,359.7208,71.126L360.4988,116.272L138.1188,83.004C138.1638,84.479,138.1928,85.353,138.1928,85.353L363.6608,119.083z" Stroke="Black" Height="52.251" Canvas.Left="45.619" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="55.486" Width="225.542"/>
                <Path Data="F1M140.393,48.651C141.171,39.051,152.328,41.126,152.328,41.126C152.328,41.126,344.326,67.591,354.705,68.629C358.353,68.994,360.746,70.192,362.321,71.593C361.387,69.211,358.894,65.78,352.245,65.115C341.867,64.078,149.869,37.613,149.869,37.613C149.869,37.613,138.712,35.537,137.934,45.137C137.155,54.737,138.193,85.353,138.193,85.353L140.554,85.706C140.314,77.645,139.768,56.367,140.393,48.651" Height="48.282" Stretch="Fill" Width="224.677" Canvas.Left="45.144" Canvas.Top="26.077">
                        <Path.Stroke>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                    </Path.Stroke>
                    </Path>

            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Check out this post, I think it's what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562192/converting-multiple-paths-into-one-big-connected-path-in-expression-blend/8562906#8562906

Comment: thanks Joel for your comment. Unfortunately I was trying with that post (this is  from I know this Object->Combine->Unite and from some reason it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you selecting multiple Path elements first?  I've loaded the code you posted in Blend and Unite is enabled.  You have to select at least two Path elements for the Combine options to become enabled.  Personally, I find it easier to select them in the Objects and Timeline panel and right-click to find the Combine menu.

Assuming that you are trying to turn this art into a single Path element, I can only say "good luck".  This kind of operation can be very tricky.  My bet is that the Path operations will not do what you actually want because overlapping elements combine properties as well as Paths.  You'll lose detail of one element or the other if they overlap.

It seems then that Compound Paths would be the answer, but Compound Paths suffer from the same issue.  Select all the Paths and use Path > Make Compound Path. On the surface this seems OK until you realize the black button in the center of the art is now white.  When you think of it, this makes sense.  You are asking a single Path to have multiple Fill properties, which it cannot do.

You can experiment with the other Path operations but they all enforce the same rules because in the end a Path isn't all that complex.  The real question I would ask is "what are you really trying to achieve"?  The only real reason to convert these all to a single Path is so that they can share the same properties.

If you tell me what problem you are trying to solve maybe we can find a solution.  The elements are already grouped together (in Layer_2).  If you are looking to make this a reusable graphic on other screens, I would group Layer_2 into a ViewBox and then export the ViewBox to a UserControl (right-click > Make Into User Control).  My guess is this is what you are actually after.